# RegEx to remove unwanted character patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, character

I need to remove some characters from a string. However, there are certain restrictions.

**Example phrase**:

*There are two '@planes' which are almost ' identical in @ how they are built.*

I need to find the pattern `'@` and the next following `'`. Those characters need to be removed from the String. However, if there is only a `'` or only a `@` they should remain untouched. To clarify, the string can contain one or more words that are enclosed by '@ at the beginning and a single ' at the end. The enclosing characters need to be removed.

After removing the characters it should look like this:

*There are two planes which are almost ' identical in @ how they are built.*

**Another example phrase:**

*A '@computer' can sometimes be very '@expensive in price' but in other cases it can be @cheap or even free'.*

After removing the characters, it should look like this:

*A computer can sometimes be very expensive in price but in other cases it can be @cheap or even free'.*

The regex should work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `/'@([a-z0-9\s]+)'/gi` work for you?

```js
"A '@computer' can sometimes be very '@expensive in price' but in other cases it can be @cheap or even free'.".replace(/'@([a-z0-9\s]+)'/gi, '$1');
```

You may check out https://regex101.com/ to get explanations in detail about the regexp itself.

Comment: The given solution seems to work as intended.
I'm completly new into regex. The provided expression correctly matches what i'm looking for. However i'm confused about the `'$1'` when replacing the matched sequence. As far as I can tell you group the  `[a-z0-9\s]+` by adding `()`, so you can later replace the whole sequence by the grouped sequence. Is that correct? How does `'$1'` refer to the group?

Comment: @NIcolas_V basicaly `$n` tells `replace` to insert n-th substring match. You may check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace, "specifying a string as a parameter" section. I think it might be `$&` as well but I use `$1` even if there's only one group actually, idk why :-)

Answer (score 1):

This one should do what you need: `/'@([^']*)'/g`

1. It looks for the `'@` (corresponding part: `'@`)
2. It takes every character, that is NOT a `'` and groups them (corresponding part: `([^']*)`)
3. It appends a `'` to the found match for the replacement

The $1 in `str.replace(regex, '$1');` references the group created in step 2

Example:

```js
const regex  = new RegExp("'@([^']*)'","g");

const testStr = "A '@computer' can sometimes be very '@expensive in price' but in other cases it can be @cheap or even free'.";

const result = testStr.replace(regex, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Seems to be very similar to the solution from @vitkarpov. What's the difference between the `+` and the `*` quantifier though?

Comment: hey, added some explanation... the difference between `+` and `*`: `+` = one or more characters, `*` = zero or more characters... it's of course similar (it's the same problem), however vitkarpov only allows alphanumeric strings and whitespaces meanwhile my solution also allows any other character ;)